# How to evaluate TensorFlow model given .pb file?

Tags: tensorflow

I have downloaded the Inception_v3 model of Tensorflow using following command:

```
curl http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz -o /tmp/inceptionv3.tgz
tar xzf /tmp/inceptionv3.tgz -C /tmp/
```

Now I have a `classify_image_graph_def.pb` file, which I believe is the model.

My question is, how to evaluate this model against the ImageNet 2012 data? Is there any scripts, or do I have to write some python code?

Answer (score 0):

The [`classify_image.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py) script in the TensorFlow GitHub repository uses that [pre-trained Inception model](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz) to perform classification on arbitrary JPEG images. You could adapt this script to evaluate it against the ImageNet 2012 data.